# Move Rows of Data to the bottom of Google Sheet based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I have been doing a lot of research and I can't really find anything that helps me. I have a google sheet data base of some sort that is constantly being added to. What I'm trying to do is find a way to automatically move an entire row to the bottom of my sheets when a specified value of "inactive" or "pass" is entered in the sheet. The values that would determine this would be found in Column L. In addition, I would like for there to be a timestamp of when the row was moved to the bottom of the sheet. Is there anyway of doing this?

I'll attach an exemplary google sheet to this question so you can see more of what I'm talking about.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfhvavB55RLiDRrHLzFR3kUDZ__svCvoCfYdotKcBNm_B0zm_DmQPxoBlshQJO2CKNHYHemYYD8jup/pubhtml

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to having a second sheet? You could provide ranking values for each type and place these in an additional column.

- Inactive = 0
- Pass = 1
- Active = 2

Setting of this value could be automated with an `arrayformula`. Then, on a second sheet, you could set up a sort function and sort by the ranked values in either ascending or descending order. As for the timestamp, you could set up an `on_edit` function to indicate a time stamp.

Cell L1 on your main sheet

```
=arrayformula(if(K1:K<>"",if(K1:K=$K!,"Rank",if(K1:=K="Inactive,L1:L=0,if(K1:K="Pass",1,if(K1:K="Active",2,"ADDMORE"))),""))
```

On the second sheet,

```
= sort(A:L,12,0)
```

`On_edit` - there are several other posts that show how to do this.